# Symfony DoctrineFixturesBundle issue with dependencies

Tags: symfony, fixtures

I have a Fixture class which depends on 2 other classes. According to documentation, for doing so I need to implement the DependentFixtureInterface, and add a method getDependencies() returning them. And I did, however I'm getting an `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'comunidad_autonoma_id' cannot be null` error. I already cleared and warmed up the cache, several times, but the error persists. What am I missing?

Here's my Fixture class...

```
<?php

namespace App\DataFixtures\AppCommon;

use App\DataFixtures\AppAdmin\UsuarioFixtures;
use App\Entity\AppCommon\ComunidadAutonoma;
use App\Entity\AppCommon\Provincia;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\DependentFixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager;

class ProvinciaFixtures extends Fixture implements DependentFixtureInterface
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $provincias = [
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Almería', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Andalucía'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Cádiz', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Andalucía'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Córdoba', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Andalucía'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Granada', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Andalucía'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Huelva', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Andalucía'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Jaén', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Andalucía'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Málaga', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Andalucía'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Sevilla', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Andalucía'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Huesca', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Aragón'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Teruel', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Aragón'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Zaragoza', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Aragón'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Las Palmas', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Canarias'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Santa Cruz de Tenerife', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Canarias'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Cantabria', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Cantabria'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Ávila', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Castilla y León'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Burgos', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Castilla y León'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'León', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Castilla y León'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Palencia', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Castilla y León'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Salamanca', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Castilla y León'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Segovia', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Castilla y León'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Soria', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Castilla y León'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Valladolid', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Castilla y León'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Zamora', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Castilla y León'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Albacete', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Castilla-La Mancha'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Ciudad Real', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Castilla-La Mancha'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Cuenca', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Castilla-La Mancha'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Guadalajara', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Castilla-La Mancha'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Toledo', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Castilla-La Mancha'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Barcelona', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Cataluña'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Gerona', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Cataluña'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Lérida', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Cataluña'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Tarragona', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Cataluña'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Ceuta', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Ciudades Autónomas'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Melilla', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Ciudades Autónomas'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Madrid', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Comunidad de Madrid'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Navarra', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Comunidad Foral de Navarra'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Alicante', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Comunidad Valenciana'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Castellón', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Comunidad Valenciana'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Valencia', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Comunidad Valenciana'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Badajoz', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Extremadura'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Cáceres', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Extremadura'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'La Coruña', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Galicia'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Lugo', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Galicia'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Orense', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Galicia'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Pontevedra', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Galicia'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Baleares', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Islas Baleares'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'La Rioja', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'La Rioja'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Álava', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'País Vasco'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Guipúzcoa', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'País Vasco'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Vizcaya', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'País Vasco'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Asturias', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Principado de Asturias'],
            ['codigo' => '', 'denominacion' => 'Murcia', 'descripcion' => '', 'comunidad_autonoma' => 'Región de Murcia']
        ];

        foreach ($provincias as $prov) {
            $provincia = new Provincia();
            $provincia->setCreatedBy($this->getReference(UsuarioFixtures::ADMIN_USER_REFERENCE)->getEmail());

            if (!empty($prov['codigo']))
                $provincia->setCodCodigo($prov['codigo']);
            if (!empty($prov['denominacion']))
                $provincia->setCodDenominacion($prov['denominacion']);
            if (!empty($prov['descripcion']))
                $provincia->setCodDescripcion($prov['descripcion']);
            if (!empty($prov['comunidad_autonoma'])) {
                $comunidadAutonoma = $manager
                    ->getRepository(ComunidadAutonoma::class)
                    ->findOneBy(['codDenominacion' => $prov['comunidad_autonoma']]);

                if ($comunidadAutonoma instanceof ComunidadAutonoma)
                    $provincia->setComunidadAutonoma($comunidadAutonoma);
            }

            $manager->persist($provincia);
        }

        $manager->flush();
    }

    public function getDependencies()
    {
        return [
            UsuarioFixtures::class,
            ComunidadAutonomaFixtures::class
        ];
    }
}
```

and here's the error I'm gettin...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Doctrine` error explicitly said that there is an `Integrity constraint violation`. The column `comunidad_autonoma_id` cannot be null. Either try to update you entity `Provincia` to mark the field `omunidadAutonoma` as nullable or check your dataset array to make sure that each `comunidad_autonoma` has a corresponding record in your database.

Comment: You're right. Later I realized that indeed, Symfony is loading the fixtures in the right order. The problem is actually in the encoding, and all the special Spanish chars. Now I'm facing this other problem, hahaha...
I'm sorry, I should have closed or at least edited this question. Thanks anyway for your answer... ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question ?

Comment: Yes, it does, kind off... Sorry for the late reply. As I said, the problem is actually with the special chars. The entity `ComunidadAutonoma` exists, it has some data, and the names in the `Provincia` dataset are correct. It's just that all those special chars are not getting correctly inserted in the DB, and therefore neither the dependant entities... Now I have to find the correct way to encode all those chars...

Comment: Great. If it answer your question you can mark it as the correct answer to help future readers

Answer (score 0):

In the for each loop you dont check if the last if faild. You have to check befor persit and stop it else.

You can do

```
if($provincia->getComunidadAutonoma() instanceof ComunidadAutonoma)
    {
        $manager->persist($provincia);
    }
```